# Borderlands 2 PS3 not saving

Tags: ps3, borderlands-2

I play Borderlands 2 on my PS3. I defeated the first boss boom beiwm 
(I think that's how you spell it), then saved and quit.

But when I decided to play the game again it took me back to the location where that guy fixed clap-trap's eye. I still kept Maya's
(the girl I play as) newly found power and all of the weapons but lost progress and had to re-defeat everyone again, including the bosses.

I  thought It just glitched or something so I continued playing and got to the next boss after the boom brothers. I saved and quit then when I reloaded the game later on it did the same thing, sending me back to that stupid location. I really don't know what would cause this.

I do have different games running on different ps3 profiles and the other game works fine. Could anyone tell me what's wrong?